# How to change used Web-service URL dynamically

Tags: .net, wcf

I have a three-tier application distributed by the internet. So I need to install it on the server and clients.

When it had been installed on the server it sent me (to my server) a server URL.
I want to distribute the client part via Click-Once. 

But in this case, I need to provide to a client the server URL. I used the URL of WCF-service on my own server during the development phase. And I need to change it to the proper one (which I have got from the server earlier).

I can't place the right URL in the config file or something like this because I don't know it. It will be known during the first run of the application only.

How can I perform this? Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create client with `Endpoint` specified

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://domainName")));
```